# Merge two tables using full outer join with a twist - nullify values from join table based on count of rows

Tags: sql-server, full-outer-join

I have two tables I would like to merge using the principles of a full outer join - but with the exception that matching rows should be nullified when number of matching rows in 'right' table is less than number of matching rows in left table - and vice versa.

This makes more sense with an example: 
The [Transactions] table below should be merged with the [Units Ordered] table - resulting in the 3td table.
Join key is both ID and Season/Ordered Season.

The [Units Ordered] table has two rows with ID 1 and Ordered Season 2017 whilst the [Transactions] table has two. I need to retrieve the values Units Ordered and Ordered Seaon for only the one matching row from [Units Ordered] table - keeping the second row from [Transactions] table but with nullified values for Units Ordered and Ordered Season.

This contradicts the whole idea of the join and I'm not sure if this is even possible.

The tables are to be loaded into Power Query and I've also tried to solve the issue here - to no avail.

Any suggestions or thoughts are much appreciated

[image: Transactions]

[image: Units Ordered]

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @l table (id int, val int default(10));
insert into @l(id) values (1),(2),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5),(5),(6);

declare @r table (id int, val int default(20));
insert into @r(id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5),(5),(7);

select *
from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by val) as rownum
from @l 
)as l
full join
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by val) as rownum
from @r 
)as r on l.id = r.id and l.rownum = r.rownum;

--..or..?
select 
    lid, case when lcount = rcount then lval end as lval, 
    rid, case when lcount = rcount then rval end as rval,
    lcount, rcount
from
(
select 
l.id as lid, l.val as lval, count(l.id) over(partition by l.id) as lcount, 
r.id as rid, r.val as rval, count(r.id) over(partition by r.id) as rcount
from @l as l
full join @r as r on l.id = r.id
) as src;
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply! But thank you so much - it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If the `unitsordered` table has only one row for a `(id, year)` combination, then in that case you can group the first table to have only one row for each `(id, year)` combination.
If not, then you would have to generate a count of rows from the `unitsordered` table first, and then keep that much of rows from the first table for that combination.